# How to add account to emails and accounts in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

Is there a way to add an option to set up an account with my own site with the Emails and Accounts settings on windows phone? Or is it limited to only those companies Microsoft partners with?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup any email account on windows phone 8.

Comment: I'm talking about like they have for LinkedIn, Facebook, etc. I'm wanting my own oauth account